# Ruby on Rails: Write inline AngularJS code with image_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby

Is there any way to get rails asset using angularjs in view?

For Example (products.html.erb):

```
<%= image_url('product_images/logo.gif') %>
```

Returns following path

**/assets/product_images/logo-9f2efe57c3bf9b9251c554c3ffa46a71342c16e04d64534ab9132fed9b697db5.gif**

However

```
<%= image_url('product_images/{{product.file_path}}') %>
```

Where product.file_path = "logo.gif"

returns only:  **/images/product_images/logo.gif**

That's why image is not displayed in the browser.

Here is image tag

```
 <img class="my-pic" ng-src="<%= image_url('product_images/{{product.file_path}}') %>" width="100%" height="300" />
```

Comment: this is where your json should contain a fully qualified url

Comment: Thanks 'apneadiving' for your time

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved by passing the complete URL to JSON.

By updating file_path attribute in model (**product.rb**)

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    def file_path
        ActionController::Base.helpers.image_path("product_images/#{self.read_attribute(:file_path)}")
    end
    ...
end
```

followed by (in **products.html.erb**)

```
<div ng-repeat="product in all_products">
    <h2 class="my-title">{{product.title}}</h2>
    <img class="my-pic" src="{{product.file_path}}"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use this:

```
<img ng-src="<%=image_path("product_images/{{product.file_path}}")%>">
```

I hope this help you.